# What will be the values of the lambda var in the following function syntax?

Tags: python, list, function, recursion

```
def func_1(a,b):
   using_a = func_2(a-b, b) 
   with_b= func_3(lambda c: func_4(b, c), using_a)
   without_b = func_1(a, b-1)
   return func_5(with_b, without_b)

//except func_1 all other functions have already been initiated.
```

I'm not able to understand how c is computed in func4(b,c)

```
with_b= func_3(lambda c: func_4(b, c), using_a)
```

note without_b and the return uses recursion.

Here's the actual full code for context the syntax above refers to the partitions part of the code..

https://pastebin.com/iZ9HbzZ8

Comment: It's still not clear what you are asking. Do you understand that `lambda c:` creates a new variable `c` which is local inside the `lambda`? Just like a function argument in a named function.

Comment: Oh ok, so it creates the local variable c...and then passes it on to func4(b,c) as well? Right! Thanks..